# ReactiveCocoa 5 Animations

Tags: ios, swift, animation, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-5

I'm trying to **animate** a view's `alpha` property after I've sent it some values via a `ReactiveSwift Signal Producer`.

The following is how I am currently doing it sans animations.

```
// Somewhere in View Model (for all code below)
let shouldShowShutter = MutableProperty<Bool>(false)

// In my View
self.shutterButton.reactive.alpha <~ self.viewModel.shouldShowShutter.map({ (show) -> CGFloat in
        return show ? 1:0.0
    })
```

I can inelegantly animate the view via:

```
self.viewModel.shouldShowShutter.producer.startWithSignal { (observer, disposable) in
            observer.map({ (show) -> CGFloat in
                return show ? 1:0.0
            }).observeValues({ [unowned self] (alpha) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
                    self.shutterButton.alpha = alpha
                })
            })
        }
```

But I should be able to animate the views with `ReactiveAnimation`:

```
self.shutterButton.reactive.alpha <~ self.viewModel.shouldShowShutter.map({ (show) -> CGFloat in
        return show ? 1:0.0
    }).animateEach(duration: 0.2).join(.Concat)
```

The question: `ReactiveCocoaLayout` and `ReactiveAnimation` both don't seem to work anymore as of the time I am asking the question, at least not with the Swift 3 or `ReactiveCocoa 5` as they depend a lot on the legacy `RACSignals`.

**Is there a more elegant way to animate signal streams to ReactiveCocoa components with ReactiveCocoa 5?**

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know about ReactiveAnimation before, but I really liked the approach.

So I updated it for RAC 5.0 / Swift 3.2, have a look at [my fork](https://github.com/iv-mexx/ReactiveAnimation). I'll also create a pull request, lets have a look if we can get the project back to life.

I've included a small iOS Demo project to demonstrate the use:

```
label.reactive.center <~ SignalProducer.timer(interval: .seconds(1), on: QueueScheduler.main)
  .map { _ in return self.randomPoint() }
  // In order to demonstrate different flatten strategies,
  // the animation duration is larger than the animation interval,
  // thus a new animation begins before the running animation is finished
  .animateEach(duration: 1.5, curve: .EaseInOut)
  // With the .concat flatten strategy, each animations are concatenated.
  // Each animation finisheds, before the next one starts.
  // This also means, that animations are queued
  .flatten(.concat)
  // With the .merge flatten strategy, each animation is performed immediately
  // If an animation is currently running, it is cancelled and the next animation starts from the current animation state
  //.flatten(.merge)
```

Comment: Did you happen to add the demo eventually or? I'd be happy to look through and see what we could possibly do to restart it all.

Comment: Ooops, I did add it as a submodule. Fixed it now, its directly in the repo: https://github.com/iv-mexx/ReactiveAnimation